# Increment mountpoint name with awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, mount, string

I am currently writing a script that makes mounting of LUKS devices easier.
In the script I do have a default mountpoint name (`data_1`), - however, if a mountpoint like that already exists, I want to increment the number suffix, test again and so on, until I find a string that is not yet a mountpoint.

For example, I can list mountpoints like so: `lsblk -o MOUNTPOINTS`.

Lets assume the the output is:

```
/
/boot
/mnt/data_1
/mnt/data_2
/mnt/data_3
/var/lib/docker
```

My default mountpoint name is `data_1`.
Now I want to get a valid new mountpoint name. In this case, this would be `data_4`, because `data_1` ,`data_2` and `data_3` already exist.
Whats the easiest way to get a name that gets incremented like this? I assume I can do some awk magic maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `awk` can come to the rescue. In this snippet, the mountpoint prefix is `data`, and it's separated from its sequence number by an underscore.

```
awk -F '_' -v mp='data' '
    BEGIN { re = "^(.*/)?" mp FS "[0-9]+$" }    # Build a RE to match relevant mountpoints
    $0 ~ re && $NF > x { x = $NF }              # Save the highest sequence number
    END { print mp FS x+1 }                     # Print the next value
'
```

Output from your example

```
data_4
```

Or, if you were to set `mp='/mnt/data'` you'd get `/mnt/data_4`. Either will work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v base='/mnt/data_' 'sub(base,"") && ($1>max){max=$1} END{print base max+1}' file
/mnt/data_4
```